# How do you use Blogger Post Image as a background image?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, blogger

I'm a novice to php, js, java, script, etc but I know HTMl and CSS.
I am looking to set a Blogger Post's First Image as a background on a div section; making essentially a small box link on the main page. I have found the following code/script within the default Blog widget:

```
<img expr:src='data:post.firstImageUrl'/>
```

This by default will generate the first image as its own element on the page but I want to set it to the background, something like this:

```
<div style="background-image: expr:src='data:post.firstImageUrl';"></div>
```

I know the above won't work due to the incorrect syntax but is there something similar that I can use?

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get the blogger first image URL in the post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27134094/how-to-get-the-blogger-first-image-url-in-the-post)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use this expression : *note the space around +*

```
<div expr:style='&quot;background-image: url(\&quot;&quot; + data:post.firstImageUrl + &quot;\&quot;);&quot;'></div>
```

Comment: That's just what I was looking for with a little help from CSS thank you, just out of interest is there a way to set the opacity of the image within that syntax without using CSS or Styles? I only ask because using either will make the parent element Opaque along with all the child elements and I'm trying to avoid this. Thanks!

Comment: There is no way to set the opacity of the background image but you can use [pseudo element trick](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/transparent-background-images/)

Comment: I may be missing something here but, whilst [link](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/transparent-background-images/) does work when you are specifiying the image url in the stylesheet; your suggested solution uses script to obtain the image url from the Blogger database within the expr:style tag within a <div> container rather than a stylesheet. The script doesn't work in CSS as a 'valid url' whether I place it in the <head> section or within a separate <style> tag just before the <div>. The use of ::after is definitely the closest I've come to a solution so is there a way to make both work?

Comment: Yes, `data:post.firstImageUrl` doesn't work in the head or outside `id='Blog1'` widget so use `<style>` before your element and to retrieve the first image url use `url(<data:post.firstImageUrl/>);` :)

Answer (score 0):

help

```
<div class="newphoto"></div>
<script>
document.getElementsByClassName('newphoto')[0].style.backgroundImage = "url('<data:blog.postImageUrl/>')" ;
</script>
```

Add the else line to javascipt

```
document.getElementsByClassName('newphoto')[0].style.backgroundImage = "url('https://1.bp.blogspot.com/-aAjLvDndDIo/WH2DcqOeX9I/AAAAAAAAI9Y/W3_fmq0uGXseb_A1XWhaj5ZyL3DzKJD9ACLcB/s1600/bgplaydefault_djhayhay247.jpg')" ;
```